# How to create a static count that doesn't break down

Tags: tableau-api

In building a dashboard in Tableau, I have had great success completing a variety of complicated calculations and views but find I'm stuck with one that seems fairly simple.  In a report I need to divide a quota amongst a number of customers.  The quota is set for each sales rep and all I need to do is distribute that quota evenly across their customers.  So, for ex, if sales rep A had a quota of $20 and 5 customers the quota for each would be $4.  I did a countD on the customer field and then use that to divide the quota and all is great at the high level display when the sales rep is the lowest level.  It counts the total customers for that sales rep and divides the total quota by that..  the problem I'm having is when I build on that table and add the customer level detail.  all of the sudden I lost my total count of customers b/c now my customer count is 1 (for each record).  So, I think what I'm trying to determine is how to create a static count for "Number of customers per sales rep" that can be used in this table and will remain constant even when drilling down to the customer level. Does this make sense?

Comment: Have you tried LOD calculations . LOD calculations does not depend upon the Grain of the Worksheet .

Comment: These appear to be EXACTLY what I need however I have Tableau 8.2 and this appears to be in the 9.0 version.  Any idea if there is a workaround to gain this functionality in the previous versions?

Comment: Version 9 is a free upgrade I think. Else you can post a public link of your workbook to visualize the problem better.

Comment: @leslie : can you post some sample data or include the `Tableau` file ?